# amend code to return True or False for numbers in sequence

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy, sequence

```
    import numpy as np                                          
    import re                                                   

    def validate(seq):                                          
        stl = "".join(np.diff(seq).astype(str))                 
        for x in re.findall("[1]+",stl):                        
            if len(x)>3:                                        
                return False                                    
        return True                                             

    print validate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20])
    print validate([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23])
    print validate([2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24])
```

**output**

```
    False
    True
    True
```

This code check the list and check how many numbers are chained and return False if there are more than 4 together like the first print (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...), returning True if there are only 4 in sequence like the second print (6, 7, 8, 9) (16, 17, 18, 19).

So how can I amend the code to return True when the list have only one group with 4 numbers in sequence? Returning False for lists with more than for numbers in sequence?

```
print validate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20])
print validate([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23])
print validate([2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24])
```

**output**

```
False
False
True
```

Comment: Perhaps nobody understand your question. You should change "numbers are chained" to ["consecutive numbers"](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/consecutive-numbers.html) and "only 4" to "at most 4". Is validate([0,1111]) suppose to be false, or this code is bad?

Comment: What are you converting to text and using a regular expression? It seems like you want to consider `10, 11, 12` to be in sequence. As numbers, they are. But the digits `'101112'` clearly are not. So clearly, if your existing code is working at all, your expectations must be very different from what you've described here.

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined validate function is somewhat hard to follow. I rewrote it in the following way

```
def validate(seq, counts=1, N=4):
    if len(seq) < N:
        return False

    diff_seq = np.diff(seq)
    sum_seq = np.array([(np.sum(diff_seq[i:i+N-1])==N-1) for i in range(len(diff_seq)-N+2)])
    return np.count_nonzero(sum_seq) == counts
```

where `N` is the length of consecutive numbers in a group and `counts` is the number of such groups that you want to have in `seq`.

**EDIT**
You can use convolve to compute sum_seq in function `validate` as follows

```
    sum_seq = np.convolve(diff_seq, np.ones((N-1,)), mode='valid') == N-1
```

This should be much faster and it looks more pythonic.